# How to programatically get all Java JRE(JVM) installed and its path using C++ language?

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, jvm

For example, there are 2 JVMs installed on a user's machine: JDK 5 JDK 6

and corresponding path should be outputted ?

Comment: I thinks this is OS-dependent code.

Answer (score 1):

If environment variables set, you can use `std::getenv` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

For example:

```
const char* PossibleEnvNames[] = { "JAVA_HOME", "JAVA_PATH", "JAVA" }; // ... etc.
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(PossibleEnvNames); ++i) {
   std::cout << std::getenv(PossibleEnvNames[i]);
}
```